# Next getStaticPaths throws error: A required parameter (slug) was not provided as an array in getStaticPaths for /[[...slug]]

Tags: reactjs, axios, next.js

I have NEXTjs connected to Strapi API. On my address http://localhost:1337/api/global?populate=* from where I get data with Axios in this format:

```
{
 "data":
 {
  "id":1,
  "attributes":
   {
    "Title":"Title",
    "links":
     [
      {"id":7, "name":"Home", "slug":"/"},
      {"id":8, "name":"Exchange students", "slug":"/exchange"},
      {"id":9,"name":"Local students","slug":"/local"},
      {"id":10,"name":"About us","slug":"/about"},            
      {"id":11,"name":"Partners","slug":"/partners"}, 
      {"id":12,"name":"FAQ","slug":"/faq"}
     ]
   }
  }
}
```

My project structure is:

```
src/
├── components
└── pages/
    ├── [[...slug]].tsx
    ├── _app.tsx
    └── _document.tsx
```

If I understand right the [[...slug]].tsx helps me with dynamic routing with use of `getStaticPaths()` and `getStaticProps()`.
So my [[...slug]].tsx filu looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { NextPage } from 'next';

const DynamicPage: NextPage = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  return <>This is page</>;
};

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const { data: result } = await axios.get(`http://localhost:1337/api/global?populate=*`);
  const paths = result
    ? result.data.attributes?.links.map((link) => {
        return { params: { slug: link.slug } };
      })
    : [];
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
};

export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const { slug } = context.params;
  
  return {
    props: {
      slug,
    },
  };
};

export default DynamicPage;
```

But this return an Error: 
`Error: A required parameter (slug) was not provided as an array in getStaticPaths for /[[...slug]]`
[image: Error]

What can I do to fix this error?
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Isn't it happening because you have extra square brackets on your file name? According to the docs, the file name to catch all routes has to be [...slug].tsx

Comment: That kinda does but double brackets are also an option https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#optional-catch-all-routes.
When I leave single brackets than for some reason I am always getting 404 error even when I return static parts as return { paths: ['/', 'exchange']}

Comment: An [optional catch-all route](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#optional-catch-all-routes) (`[[...slug]].tsx`) expects an array of strings as the parameter value (not a string), but you most likely do not need that for your use case. A simple dynamic route like `[slug].tsx` would be enough. You should also pass the `slug` values without the leading `/`, e.g. `slug: 'exchange'` instead of `slug: '/exchange'`.

Comment: @ŠimonSlabý did you find a fix?

Comment: @Mykyta, I did. Posted final answer under.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [[...slug]].tsx uses routing for all the pages provided in GetStaticPaths. Here I was supposed to provide a slug without slash `/`, I achieved it by mapping `data`, where I split the string into 2 pieces from `link`. For example, having slug: `/exchange` would split into `['/', 'exchange]`, where by using `.substring(1)` I was able to pass `params: {slug: exchange}`

```
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const { data: result } = await API.get(`/pages?fields[0]=slug`);

  const paths = result
    ? result.data.map((link: GlobalsLinks) => {
        return {
          params: {
            slug: link.slug!.toString().substring(1).split('/'),
          },
        };
      })
    : [];

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: 'blocking'
  };
};
```

Inside `GetStaticProps` I handled it like this:

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const slug = context.params?.slug ?? null;

  const { data: result }: Pages = await API.get(
    `/pages?filters[slug]=/${
      slug !== null ? (slug as string[]).join('/') : ''
    }&populate=*`
  );

  if (result?.data === undefined) {
    return {
      props: {
        pageContent: null,
      },
    };
  }

  return {
    props: {
        pageContent: result?.data[0],
    },
    revalidate: 20,
  };
};
```